# Exclude angular spec files from testing - Chutzpah

Tags: jasmine, chutzpah

I am writing test cases in Jasmine and using Chutzpah to run them , I want to include a certain spec files for testing and exclude remain all other spec files or vice-versa I.e exclude all unneeded spec files . I can't delete the spec files which I don't need as those are part of angular packages and bootstrap packages .

Answer (score 1):

There is a Tests section in the config file chutzpah.json that does exactly what you are looking for.

Example:

```
{
    "Tests": [
        { "Includes": ["*test1*"] },
        { "Path": "Dir3/test.js"},
        { "Path": "Dir1", "Includes": ["*.js"], "Excludes": ["*test4.js"] },
        { "Path": "Dir2" }
    ]
}
```

https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/tests-setting